# LDAP Fault-tolerance configuration (e.g SunOne)

Tags: ldap, fault-tolerance, sunone

LDAP Fault-tolerance configuration (e.g SunOne):
Does anyboby know how to configuration "Fault-tolerance" for LDAP, e.g SunOne LDAP.

I search via google without any userful result?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, by "fault tolerance," "high availability (HA)" is being asked, I would say it can be achieved by redundancy. And, it would not be peculiar to SunOne or any directory server software from other vendors.

There are different ways to solve this. It depends on the business requirements and the affordability. One method that comes to mind is to have the LDAP software installed on an HA pair. This requires hardware and OS capabilities for fail-over and it requires two servers (in a world of virtualization, "server" can mean different things [physical box, frame, LPAR, etc.]; so, I'll just leave the interpretation to the reader). When one server fails, the other server takes over and assumes the primary role in the pair. This is the fault-tolerance part. In this approach, the machine/server with the secondary role is passive (i.e., it's not serving clients) until the primary goes down. You will need to implement LDAP data replication between two servers. They can be two LDAP masters in a P2P replication topology.

Another method is to have multiple LDAP servers (i.e., masters, replicas) and cluster them using a network dispatcher (ND) software/appliance/etc., which would distribute the incoming traffic to the individual servers (usually replicas) in the cluster. If you lose one replica in the cluster, ND will not send any traffic to that replica until it comes back. However, other replicas will still be receiving load and therefore serving to the incoming traffic. This is the fault-tolerance part in this method. The degree of the availability you want will also dictate what can be done in a clustered environment. You can have a single LDAP master (to which the organization's applications would make updates) and keep it out of the cluster, but pair with another server for fail-over (so you wouldn't lose availability for updates from the applications - this also gives you the freedom to do maintenance on the master without interrupting your applications [well, they need to be written to be able to write to more than one LDAP master if the primary one is not available]). You would have to have the secondary server to receive replication from the primary in any case. If the budget doesn't let you have more servers/replicas, then you can put the master server along with replicas in the cluster as well to help with the read traffic. Instead of an HA-pair in which one of the servers would be passive, you can have two masters configured in a P2P replication topology and have them both in the cluster to help with the traffic too. There are different ways to approach to this method depending on the level of redundancy wanted or that can be afforded.